# A method that returns a new array by eliminating * * the duplicate values in the array

Tags: java, arrays

```
/** eleminateDuplicates returns a new array with duplicate values eliminated */
    public static int[] eliminateDuplicates(int[] list) {
        int[] distinctList = new int[list.length];
        int i = 0;  // index distinctList
        for (int e: list) {
            if (linearSearch(distinctList, e) == -1) {
                distinctList[i] = e;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return distinctList;
    }

    /** linearSearch */
    public static int linearSearch(int[] array, int key) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (key == array[i])
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

For example if i insert 10 numbers 9,9,9..., and print it, the result is only 9.
I cant understand the logic of these methods. When u return i from linearSearch method, does it break from the loop?
Can u explain me step by step how the logic of these methods works!

Comment: Yes, the `return` statement will return from the method immediately, breaking the loop.

Comment: Now that you know `return` breaks the loop, which part of the logic confuses you?

Comment: when u break from the loop and return i, do u also retun -1 same time?

Comment: Which part of "return from the method immediately" could mean that the other return statement would be executed? Besides, there is only one return value, so how could it return 2 values at the same time?

Comment: sorry im a beginner, if u could explain me (linearSearch(distinctList, e) == -1) how this works with the method linearSearch.

Comment: If `linearSearch` finds the value, it returns `i`, which is `0` or higher. If it doesn't find the value, it returns `-1`. So what do you think testing if the return value is `-1` is trying to do?

Comment: (linearSearch(distinctList, e) == -1) it will be excecuted.

Comment: @Andreas look i tried to understand it but i still dont get it, could u please explain it to me? (linearSearch(distinctList, e) == -1) what numbers do distinctList, and e get, so that in (key == array[i]) it returns i, and when it returns i here in (key == array[i]) it will not be executed!  I just dont understand the concept , if u insert an array with 10 numbers, 1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8 it will return 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8! i just dont understand these methods how they get the numbers and do the work. If u could help me that would be great cause im stuck 2 days in this code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you understanding the flow, but I strongly recommend to learn to use a debugger, it will help you debug and understand the code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        eliminateDuplicates(new int[]{1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3});
    }

    public static int[] eliminateDuplicates(int[] list) {
        int[] distinctList = new int[list.length];
        int i = 0;
        // Iterate through each array elements
        for (int e : list) {
            // Verify if the value already exist. If the number exist return the index of the first apparition, otherwise -1.
            if (linearSearch(distinctList, e) == -1) {
                // Put the value to the distinctList is unique
                distinctList[i] = e;
                // Move to the next position in the distinctList array
                i++;
                System.out.printf("Element %d is not in the distinct array, so it will be added %s\n", e, Arrays.toString(distinctList));
            } else {
                System.out.printf("Element %d already in the distinct array, so it will be skipped\n", e);
            }
        }
        // Return the distinctList that contain only unique values
        return distinctList;
    }

    public static int linearSearch(int[] array, int key) {
        // Iterate through each array elements
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            // Check the current value of the array (array[i]) if it is the same with the given one return the current index
            if (key == array[i])
                // Same value, no need to search any more, so return from the method with the index of the value
                return i;
        }
        // If the value was not found (the above condition "key == array[i]" was never true)
        return -1;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Element 1 is not in the distinct array, so it will be added [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Element 2 is not in the distinct array, so it will be added [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Element 1 already in the distinct array, so it will be skipped
Element 2 already in the distinct array, so it will be skipped
Element 3 is not in the distinct array, so it will be added [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
Element 3 already in the distinct array, so it will be skipped
```